# chrome://newtab loads delta search

Tags: google-chrome

I have wasted nearly 4 hours in fixing this.

After Babylon this time it is delta-search which makes my chrome sucks on every new tab. chrome://newtab loads: http://www2.delta-search.com/?babsrc=NT_ss_SU&mntrId=786E00E04C01EE9A&affID=121564&tsp=4987

I am not able to fix this. I have already fixed homepage, search setting and other browsers. Please help me to fix this new tab issue. I want "Most visited tab" to be there when I press new tab button.

A real solution is to reset some fields in "chrome://flags". This was the way I did last time in AVG or Babylon. I have solved my problem but I wish if someone could really give exact  steps so that next time if a user gets stuck he can find it here.
:p

Comment: Did you try to go to settings -> extensions and check if there is anything there? Perhaps there is something called "delta" where you can remove it.

Comment: This question is not a programming question

Comment: try unistalling from application manager. You might have something there

Comment: In google - "How to remove babylon extension from chrome"

Comment: @Ben Mezger yes, I did everything. Even fixed it but this time not perfectly.

Comment: @ Jaguar I know but needed it urgently. This is good place with all people who are using chrome in developer mode.

others I was actually finding a way to fix it. I got it last time but this time it was too difficult to find. I have uninstalled all the apps which were supposed to be thrashed.

Good News: I got it myself. chrome://flags and click reset all to default.
Bad News: It is not perfect solution. I am still looking for specific fields that are to be reset or changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open google chrome, type chrome://flags/ on address bar and go to hidden configuration setting.
change following part of configuration file to *disable* by cliking on *enable*..

**Enable Tab Browser Dragging Windows**
Enable creating a browser window when dragging tabs. #enable-tab-browser-dragging
Disable

Comment: i have the same problem, but I can't find **enable tab browser dragging windows** in chrome://flags... and I can't see any hidden configuration setting. Maybe something has change from the days when the answer was written. Could you help me?